# NUnit parallelization of TestFixtures per distinct constructor argument

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have an NUnit test project containing a bunch of Test classes/fixtures each of which inherits from an abstract base class hierarchy. These sealed test classes all have a TestFixtureSource attribute attached at the class level:

```
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(ExecutionBrowsers))]
public sealed class MyTestClass : TestBase
```

Where ExecutionBrowsers is defined:

```
internal sealed class ExecutionBrowsers : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Browser.Chrome;
        yield return Browser.Edge;
        yield return Browser.Firefox;
    }
}
```

So essentially each test class will be instantiated 3 times, once for each browser. I want to run these tests in parallel in such as way that a browser does not have more than one test using it at the same time (I have a hard limitation on this - lets not get into that). So what I did was to add a .cs file at the root of the project and stick the following attributes in it:

```
[assembly: NUnit.Framework.FixtureLifeCycle(NUnit.Framework.LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase)]
[assembly: NUnit.Framework.Parallelizable(NUnit.Framework.ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
[assembly: NUnit.Framework.LevelOfParallelism(3)]
```

This doesn't quite work though, it does not restrict tests to one per browser at any given time. It will start off with the first test in the first test class (some classes have more than one test) running that on each of the three browsers. However if one browser takes longer than the others it will get out of sync and begin executing two tests on one browser.

How can I achieve the behaviour that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Well see, we have a situation unit test frameworks do not run tests of the same collection asynchronously so you must rethink the structure of your unit test so that they are separate from each other, I didn't see enough of your structure to be able to assist in this restructuring

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to achieve fine control by putting attributes at the assembly level. There are lots of ways that can go wrong and you have discovered one of them. I recommend avoiding use of assembly-level `ParallelizableAttribute` unless you are absolutely sure that the specified parallel behavior will work for all your test fixtures as well as any you or others may add in the future. ;-)

Instead, add [Parallelizable] to the class. It will apply to each of your instances and will allow them to run against one another. The individual test cases will be non-parallelizable by default *with respect to one another*.

For the other attributes, you should eliminate `[FixtureLifeCycle]` unless you have a specific reason why you need it, i.e. unless your tests are running in parallel and changing the state of the fixture. You should only use `[LevelOfParallelism]` if it is needed for performance and should not count on it to keep any particular set of tests from running with one another.

You have not said how you run the tests. The above will work if you are running straight nunit console plus framework from the command line. If you are using Visual Studio, there are some other considerations because Test Explorer can change what NUnit thinks you are doing based on how it runs the tests.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, I am running in Visual studio typically while developing. However that is not a deal breaker, I could run using the nunit console runner instead. In my CICD pipeline (Jenkins) I am running using `dotnet test` but again I could use the nunit console runner there too. For clarity all tests run on all 3 browsers and all tests are independent of each other and always will be (hope I didn't jynx it). I use the `[FixtureLifeCycle]` because there are a few private fields (literally a few) in some of classes with multiple tests that I don't want to be shared between those tests.

Comment: Sorry for second comment, I wrote too much. Is the use of `[FixtureLifeCycle]` actually problematic then?

Comment: Not problematic, just not needed for the problem. If you need it for other reasons, I wouldn't use it at the assembly level, but would only use it where actually needed.

Comment: But here's an alternative point of view... Some people basically wish NUnit had been designed to use one fixture per test case in the first place. They can get their wish by using the attribute globally and eliminating all use of OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown in their test fixtures. :-)